# Pass event and this objects to function in different scope

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am building a google maps application, and I need to pass event specific data to another function in JavaScript.

When I click on part of the map, an InfoWindow pops up with information, for example latLng.  It also has a button.  When clicked, it opens an overlay with more information, part of that information is from the click event.  I need to pass the `event` and `this` objects to the button to display information in the overlay.

First I create the event:

```
// Add a listener for the mouse event.
// In the google maps scope
google.maps.event.addListener(SomeMapArea, 'click', showTB);
```

Then I have the Text Box function:

```
// In the google maps scope
function showTB(event) {

    var contentString = event.latLng + 
        '<br>' + '<button onclick="moreInfo(event, this)">More</button>';

    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map);

}
```

When I click the button the overlay with more information comes up:

```
// In global scope
function moreInfo(e, t){  //using (event, this) here causes 'missing formal parameter' error
    // Overlay code
    var overlayContent = e.latLng + t.someAttribute;

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = overlayContent;
}
```

However, `event` and `this` are not defined in the function `moreInfo`.  How do I pass those two objects into `moreInfo` so that I can read their attributes?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
var contentString = event.latLng + 
    '<br>' + '<button onclick="moreInfo('+event+','+this+')">More</button>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it caused a syntax error.  What is the significance of the `+` signs?

Comment: Sorry, i did some mistake. Edited the answer. If you are trying to get the event object from that scope, you have to write it in this way.

Comment: when you write - moreInfo(event, this) the event will be the click event of button. which doesn't contains latLng properties.

Comment: I still get the same syntax error at `moreInfo(`.  Ah, that makes sense.  So I just need to find out how to get around the syntax error

Comment: Try now. before event was passed as string. Now It will be an object.

Comment: your solution did return an object, but then threw `missing ] after element list` error.  So I restructured it, found the solution here:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565930/missing-after-element-list-for-google-maps-event-object