# missing ] after element list for google maps event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to call moreInfo() function on the onclick event and to give it information about the click event.

here are code samples:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(SomeArea, 'click', showTB);

function showTB(event) {

    //content has the map click event
    var contentString = event.latLng +
        '<br>' + '<button onclick="moreInfo('+event+')">More</button>';


    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
}
```

here is relevant function moreInfo

```
function moreInfo(e){

    var overlayContent = e.latLng
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = overlayContent;
}
```

firebug output:

> SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
>
> moreInfo([object Object])

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can't pass in `event` like that

Comment: @Prisoner I realize that might be the problem, but how else do I pass the event from the map mouse-click?

Comment: Why not extract what you need out of the event and pass it in. onclick=moreinfo(' + event.latlng.lat + ',' + event.latlng.lng + ')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the content for an `infoWindow` may also be a `DOMNode`.

Create a `DOMNode` and insert the button into this node, then you'll be able to apply a click-listener to the button(and pass any type of argument):

```
function showTB(event) {

  var contentElement = document.createElement('div'),
      btn            = document.createElement('button');
  contentElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(event.latLng));
  contentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  contentElement.appendChild(btn);
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('More'));
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn,'click',function(){ moreInfo(event);})
  infoWindow.setContent(contentElement);

}
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/N5Etg/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/N5Etg/)

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Would you, however, please tell me why its `function(){moreInfo(event)}` and not just `moreInfo(event)`?  And is is possible to add `this` into the argument?

Comment: the listener has to be a function, `moreInfo(event)` is not a function, it's a function-call and will be executed immediately(not when the click occurs)